# How do I pass a parameter with Expression as value in ADFv2?

Tags: dataset, parameter-passing, dynamic-programming, sftp, azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory v2 (ADFv2) I am having trouble passing a parameter whose value is an expression that needs evaluated at runtime.

For example, I have a set of extracts I want to download daily from the same LinkedService/Connection.  I want a pipeline with a Foreach to be able to input a JSON pipeline parameter with a list of configuration for each report type (this I can do).  "but" when I have one of those configuration KVPairs with value that is an expression, the expression does not seem to be evaluated.

here is an example of a Foreach parameter set that works for an SFTP LinkedService :

```
[ { "dirPath" : "/dirPath" ,"fileFilter" : "this_works_fine_20180307*.txt" } ]
```

here is an example of a Foreach parameter set that does not match the files I need to get.
(assume utcnow('yyyyMMdd') returns 20180307

[ { "dirPath" : "/dirPath" ,"fileFilter" : "this_does_NOT_work_@{utcnow('yyyyMMdd')}*.txt" } ]

This assumes that in the underlying Copy activity I am passing the dataset parameter fileFilter as

```
@item().fileFilter
```

...and in the dataset, the value of the fileFilter is an expression with value

```
@dataset().fileFilter
```

...I have also tried to wrap the argument completely as:

```
[ { "dirPath" : "/dirPath" ,"fileFilter" : "@toLower(concat(string('this_does_NOT_work_'),string(utcnow('yyyyMMdd')),string('*.txt') )))" } ]
```

...If you have suggestions/guidance, please let me know.

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the fileFilter parameter directly in pipeline parameter.

Something like this will work:

[ { "dirPath" : "/dirPath" ,"fileFilter" : "this_works_fine_@{formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy')}@{formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'MM')}@{formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'dd')}*.txt" } ]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response.  Can you be more specific on what you mean by "directly in pipeline parameter" ?  The example you've supplied is quite similar to the example I've provided that does not seem to work.  One challenge is that the input to my job will come from a lookup eventually, and not be hardcoded.

Comment: Hi, I coldn't make it directly from lookup, because it came as string. For an work around you could write directly in Data Factory v2 in pipeline settings area. There your expression will be evaluated at runtime, If I found solution for lookup I'll tell you.

Comment: Yeah it is probably assuming that the external caller is doing this type of stuff.  I put in a roadmap request.  I voted up your response because I appreciate your help.

Comment: what is the settings area?

Comment: Is where you can add parameters to an activity in Pipeline.
For instance, if you add an U-SQL activity, you have in tab Script the parameters area.